# Removing sheet from Excel 2005 using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to delete sheets from an Excel2005/Excel5 file using PHP. I am using PHPExcel-1.7.9. I am using the following code to delete Excel2007 files as follows

```
    $exceltype="Excel2007"; 
    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($exceltype);
    $excel = $excel->load("ABC.xlsx");

    $count = $excel->getSheetCount();
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $excel->removeSheetByIndex(0);
    }
```

When I use it for Excel5, I get an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5::getSheetCount()
```

Comment: Did you change exceltype to "Excel2005"?

Comment: Don't use the same variable name for the Reader and for the PHPExcel object that you're loading using that reader..... and use the `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify()` method to determine what reader you should be using, don't trust any file extension

Comment: @kojow7 I changed the excel type to "Excel5"

Comment: @MarkBaker could you give me an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Potential Issue #1**

Use a different variable name for the Reader and for the object that you're loading from the Reader

```
$exceltype="Excel2007"; 
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($exceltype);
$excel = $excelReader->load("ABC.xlsx");
```

**Potential Issue #2**

It's always sensible to let PHPExcel identify the filetype for you rather than trusting to the file extension

```
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("ABC.xlsx");
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files)